# How to display Video in Framelayout to portrait mode in Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

When I launch the application, I need to open the rear camera and display the video. I am using FrameLayout for this. I am able to open the camera and display the video. But the video is getting displayed in landscape mode even though I set the screen orientation as Portrait. Below is the code.

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity.this.setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // NOT WORKING ------------------------------
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView wifiTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifi_text);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        int rssi = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
        wifiTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        wifiTextView.setText(Integer.toString(rssi));

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "No camera permission");
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "camera permission");
                mCamera = getCameraInstance();
                mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
                FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
                preview.addView(mPreview);
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Use camera in OnCreate");
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
        }
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // NOT COMING HERE -------------------------------------------------------
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "COnfiguration LANDSCAPE");
        }
        else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Log.d(TAG, "COnfiguration PORTRAIT");
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Default code");
        }
    }
}
```

**CameraPreview.java :**

```
/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);

        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wifi_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I set the screen Orientation of MainAcitivity as PORTRAIT in Manifest and screen Orientation of FrameLayout as PORTRAIT in Layout. Still Video is getting displayed in Landscape mode. Can any one please let me know how to display Video in Portrait mode programatically.

Comment: please add and try this  `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` inside CameraPreview constructor method

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. Can you please post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` inside `CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera)` constructor method and try.

> `setDisplayOrientation(int)` method sets value clockwise and the
>   valid values are 0, 90, 180, and 270.

Inorder to set orientation to output video, please add `mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);` after creating instance of MediaRecorder, as like below

```
 mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
 mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
```

setOrientationHint() will set the rotation angle to the output(recorded) video.

For more information, please refer the below links

**1.setDisplayOrientation(int)**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera#setDisplayOrientation(int)[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera#setDisplayOrientation(int))

**2.setOrientationHint(int)**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setOrientationHint(int)

Comment: satuser, is there any way to check whether the video is being played in portrait mode or landscape mode programmatically? Because in Android Studio emulator, Video is being played Portrait mode before the changes. Now with 'mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90)' change, emulator video is being played in Landscape mode.

Comment: I updated the answer, please update the code and try again